# Country field for local default Country in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, field, country

How to use `Locale::getDefault()` for country field or in choice field with country names?

I have tried ->`add('agentCity','country')` but I don't know how to use `Locale::getDefault()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create a dropdown list of languages using the `language` field type: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/language.html.

Then you can specify the default value using `empty_data`, assuming that `Locale::getDefault()` is in the languages list:

```
$form->add('agentCity', 'language', array('empty_data' => Locale::getDefault()));
```

Comment: It's probably generating an error but you have `display_errors` off. Turn `display_errors` on or check your log files for the error.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I am getting all other errors, But only on this occasion I am getting blank page....

Comment: It's impossible to debug without knowing the error, check your logs.