# Locale::getDefault() gives me blank page

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to use `Locale::getDefault()` in a form like this thread : [Country field for local default Country in symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514842/country-field-for-local-default-country-in-symfony-2) when I use `Locale::getDefault()` that gives me a blank page (100% blank no symfony error) it only works when I do `\Locale::getDefault(`) ... Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happen because uses namespace. Without the slash assumes that is current namespace and with slash assumes that is in one of the namespaces starts at global.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess that the correct answer, but then why symfony doc and examples use it without the slash ?